# Layout of the page on small screens

Tags: css, mobile

You can see the sample image below, my layout... The web site works fine enough. But I used an image on left side, out of the content part.

So, if visited via a small screen like notebook or mobile, the content part doesnt fit to the screen. It starts to show from left side of the image. So, the content part flows out on right side a bit and unlike any other 960 px website the content doesnt fit to the screen. It flows out a bit on right side because there is the image for 150 px wide.

[image: layout]

How can I solve this?

No need to show the image if visited via small screens. Or.. is there any other solution?

Edit: JsFiddle

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yHC4w/)

Comment: The diagram is helpful, but your HTML would help a bit more.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I dont know why is this website so difficult to use?

Comment: It's not. Paste in a code snippet, highlight, then select the "{}" code formatting button.

Comment: Better use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: I cannot add JSFiddle links here. Stackoverflow is full of very nice and helpful coder friends but the website is killing difficult to use

Answer (score 3):

Simply allow to show your content with lesser width.

For mobile optimation you should also add some meta tags to control the zoom factor.

Like this here:

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

For adding special css rules try this here:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
/* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 630px) {
    ...
}

/* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    ...
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you so much man. It's a cool tip. I will consider them but my question is about alignment because of the image on left. How can I align the image left and the content part in order to fit to screen when viewed via small screens.

Comment: There are several options. E.g. you could float that image. With some dirty `display:table` and `display:cell` stuff you can also reorder the tags. If you need more details feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CSS media queries](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) to target smaller screen sizes, and then either move the image below your content, or hide the image altogether. Now, keep in mind that if you hide the image with display:none; it will still download, but simply isn't displayed.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's nice help about mobile css. But my question is about alignment because of the image on left