# How can I change the float of an element when on mobile

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a navbar using the following code. On desktop, I want it to be side by side, however when on mobile I want it to look like a standard list, with each `li` below the previous. I want to just use 1 css file, with as few changes as possible between the two. How can I change the layout on differint devices just by using 1 css file?

HTML:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="navitem"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="navitem"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li class="navitem"><a href="resume.php">Resume</a></li>
        <li class="navitem"><a href="projects.php">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="navitem"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- navbar -->
```

CSS:

```
/** Navbar Settings */
div#navbar{
    width      : 90%;
    min-height : 25px;
    margin     : 0 auto;
}

div#navbar li{
    display          : inline;
    text-decoration  : none;
    float            : left;
}

div#navbar li.navitem{
    font-size        : 14pt;
    width            : 20%;
    text-align       : center;
}

li.navitem a:visited{
    color            : #9BC2EF; /* Darker Blue */
    text-decoration  : none;
}
```

I already looked at [Layout of the page on small screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800447/layout-of-the-page-on-small-screens), and it doesn't really answer my question, because I want to avoid the use of media tags, because I have had issues with using them in the past.

Comment: Why dont you go for `foundation`  or  `bootstrap` for this?

Comment: @varunvlalan Because I like to avoid external dependencies in my projects